# What is the logic to recursively subdivide an octree?

Tags: recursion, octree

I am trying to recursively subdivide an octree and I am struggling with the logic of how to allow each node to be visited, but preventing an infinite recursion.

It only seems to be visiting the first node, and then stopping and I understand why it is doing this, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I am defining a `maxDepth` of 2, and a `currentDepth` which is supposed to increment once all child nodes have been subdivided. I initially pass in the root node and it should recursively go through until the max depth is reached.

This is what I have so far, where depth 1 works fine and it gets subdivided, but when I want a `maxDepth` of 2, it will only visit the first node and leave the rest.

Here is the code I am using to subdivide.

```
private void subdivideNode(OctreeNode node)
{
    if (currentDepth >= maxDepth) return;

    node.subdivide();
    currentDepth++;
    for (int i = 0; i < node.children.Length; i++)
    {
        subdivideNode(node.children[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

The `subdivide` method in `OctreeNode` creates the 8 octants of a given node

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by using

```
  private void subdivideNode(OctreeNode node, int depth)
    {
        if (depth == maxDepth) return;

        node.subdivide();

        for (int i = 0; i < node.children.Length; i++)
        {
            subdivideNode(node.children[i], depth + 1);
        }
    }
```